# Do the triangles in an "icosphere" (geodesic polyhedron) all have the same solid angle from the center?

Tags: geometry, spheres, angle, solid-angle

An "icosphere" has the mathematical name [geodesic polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_polyhedron). It's an approximation to a sphere made out of triangles with either 5 or 6 triangles meeting at a vertex. It can be made by a subdivision of a dodecahedron into triangles. The number of subdivisions determines what type of icosphere you have.

[image]

My question:

> Do the triangles in an icosphere all have the same solid angle from the center?

I expect that all triangles on a 6-vertex are equivalent and that all triangles on a 5-vertex are all equivalent, so I can't see that they would be the same.

> If they are different, is there a way to know the solid angle for any given size icosphere?

[image]

Comment: Please, give the definition of the word "icosphere", largely unknown ...

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry, I don't know it by any other name. It's an approximation to a sphere made out of triangles with either 5 or 6 triangles meeting at a vertex. It can be made by a subdivision of a dodecahedron into triangles. The number of subdivisions determines what type of icosphere you have.

Comment: @JeanMarie Googling what I just typed revealed: Geodesic polyhedron